# Exercise: Set theory identities‬

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this 2 exercises that i need to reach from one side to another side:

[image]

I try to solve it and look at the Math identities‬‏ that i have learned and with `De Morgan's laws` with no success, can anyone can help me with that ?

Comment: I can not see anything.

Comment: You cannot see the pic ?

Comment: The usual way to solve those kind of exercise is to exploit the common structure of *boolean lagebras* of set opeartions and propositional connectives. I mean that $x \in A \cup B$ iff $x \in A \lor x \in B$ and $x \in A \cap B$ iff $x \in A \land x \in B$. So $x \in (A_1 \cup A_2) \backslash (B_1 \cap B_2)$ iff $x \in (A_1 \cup A_2)$ and $x \notin (B_1 \cap B_2)$ iff ($x \in A_1$ or $x \in A_2$) and ($x \notin B_1$ and $x \notin B_2$), and so on ...

Comment: @user3328870:yes I can not see the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the second one means, but for the first one, simply use the fact that $A-B=A\cap B^c$. Then

$(A_1\cup A_2)-(B_1\cap B_2)=(A_1\cup A_2)\cap (B_1^c\cup B_2^c)$ ...

From then on, it's pretty simple. Write $C=A_1\cup A_2$, then

$C\cap (B_1^c\cup B_2^c) = (C\cap B_1^c) \:\:\cup\:\: (C\cap B_2^c)$.

Then $C\cap B_1^c = A_1\cap B_1^c \cup A_2\cap B_1^c = (A_1-B_1)\cup (A_2-B_1)$.

Do the same with $C\cap B_2^c$ and you have the first one.

For the second one, just note that

$B^c-A^c=B^c\cap A=A\cap B^c=A-B$.

Comment: That's what i did but after that i am stuck...

Comment: The "circled cross" is [*symmetric difference*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) : it is defined as $(A \backslash B) \cup (B \backslash A)$ and "works" like the XOR (exclusive or) *propositional connective*.

Comment: Yes, thanks, so the problem is solved now :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the wife took control over my computer... thanks a lot for your help !